# How to use ICallBack Event Handler

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, icallbackeventhandler

I have 2 drop down lists, on 1st DDL selected index changed event I am filling 2nd DDL.... Its a regular postback of asp.net..

In this scenario I want to use ICallBack event handler....

So how can i use this ???

Regards,
Rohit Pundlik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can google it :

1. [Client-Callback Implementation (C#) Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178210%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
2. [Implementing Client Callbacks Programmatically Without Postbacks in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
3. [The ICallbackEventHandler](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27172/The-ICallbackEventHandler)